# 4GB/4GB Kernel VM Split

Tags: linux, memory, virtual, kernel

Friends,

I saw [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/39283/) by Ingo Molnar, a famous Linux Kernel enthusiast where he talks about 4GB/4GB split.

In this article he says that

> with the 4G/4G patch, the kernel can be compiled in 4G/4G mode, in which
>   case there's a full, separate 4GB VM for the kernel, and there are
>   separate full (and per-process) 4GB VMs for user-space.

My problem starts here:

1. My assumption was that in a *monolithic kernel* like as in Linux, the *kernel* and *user* part of process shares same PROCESS ADDRESS SPACE. So with a Linux kernel that does **not** have this 4G/4G patch, we have 3/1 split for user virtual space and kernel virtual space respectively.
   In fact kernel's 1GB  virtual space is mapped in every process' virtual address space. Put it simple, PROCESS ADDRESS SPACE is 4GB, out which 1GB is allotted to kernel. Is it true?
2. Going by the article in the question - and if my assumption as said in 1) is right - does he mean that the kernel address space is no more mapped into PROCESS ADDRESS SPACE and we have a different virtual address space for kernel and there is no sharing of address space?
   That is PROCESS ADDRESS SPACE is 4GB and KERNEL ADDRESS SPACE is another 4GB; rather than the fact that PROCESS ADDRESS SPACE has enlarged to become 8GB out of which 4GB is shared for kernel.

I know I am sounding bit stupid here :).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that 4G/4G mode is basically unnecessary now, as any system large enough to need it can probably run in 64-bit mode now.

Comment: The *process address space* can't become 8GB because the pointer is still 32 bits. Unless word-based addressing is used, which is not possible in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the article correctly, the kernel and the userspace don't share the same address space after the patch. This however costs switching page tables during each userspace/system switch.

Comment: The patch leaves a 16MB trampoline area at the top of the 4GB address space shared between user and kernel, but otherwise correct.

Comment: AFAIK Solaris on Sparc have distinct spaces for kernel and user because it has hardware support for that http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3024/6j2sumi4b/index.html